# Difference format_tags and stylesSet

Tags: ckeditor

What is the difference between the `format_tags` property and the `stylesSet` property in the CKEDITOR config?

I'm using the API for some custom buttons (which are elsewere in the DOM, not in the editor itself) and I also have a dropdown for styles.

I first used the `format_tags` property:

```
var tags = config.format_tags.split( ';' );
// Create style objects for all defined styles.
var styles = {};
$.each(tags,function(i,tag) {
  styles[ tag ] = new CKEDITOR.style( config[ 'format_' + tag ] );
  styles[ tag ]._.enterMode = ckeditor.config.enterMode;
});
```

After this I could call the desired style function to apply (or remove) it.

Today I stumbled upon the `stylesSet` property, I can use it like this:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('my_custom_style', [
  { name: 'My Custom Block', element: 'h3', styles: { color: 'blue'} },
  { name: 'My Custom Inline', element: 'span', attributes: {'class': 'mine'} }
]);
```

This looks better for me, because I know can use extra classes and inline style for an element.

Can somebody explain why there are two ways to format text? Why is the `format_tags` used when you have a better configuration option like `stylesSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into it. It seems that you can use the same format for a `format_tag` as a `stylesSet`.

I now have this in my config:

```
config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;h3;test';
config.format_test = { element : 'span', attributes : { 'class' : 'test' }, styles: { color: 'blue'} };
```

This works the best for adding custom format-tags to your ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different language, don't forget to add the a custom tag translation to the "format" section. ../lang/nl.js Else the new tag is not visible in the format dropdownlist.

```
"format": {
  .......       
  "tag_test": "tekst met css"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I want to add a custom **section** tag to format tags, this work for me:
1. Go to config.js, add 
config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;**section**'; 
**config.format_section = { element : 'section', attributes : { 'class' : 'test' } };**
2. Then open the languagefile you want (e.g. en.js) -> lang/en.js 
search for "tag_pre":"Formatted", and add **"tag_section":"Section"**.

Answer (score 0):

There are actualy two drop-down lists. One for **Tag selection**, second for **Style selection**. Visibility of these fields in the toolbar can be changed in configuration.
[image]

### Tag drop-down list

changes current block element tag type (p, h1, h2, ...). Configuration for this list is for example `format_tags: 'p;h2;h3;h4;div;pre'`. [Learn more here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_format)

### Style drop-down list

changes various settings of currently selected element (not only block element). Using this you can for example give certain class to an image. Configuration for this list is for example:

```
stylesSet: [
            {
                name : 'Image on the left',
                element : 'img',
                attributes : { 'class' : 'myLeftImage' }
            }
        ]
```

[Learn more here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles)